# Refreshing JPanel after loading next Image into it

Tags: java, image, swing, slideshow, thread-sleep

I have created `ImagePanel` which is able to display images from the specified directory -> it sleeps 1 second and loads next image from the java project's directory. 
It actually loads next image but it is not displayed(it does not refresh the panel), when it is done with all the files from the directory it shows only the last image from the directory.  I would like to make it refresh after loading every image.

```
  import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Okno extends JFrame {
    JPanel jp;
    ImagePanel ImagePanel;
    JButton buttonExit;
    JButton buttonWyjscie;

    public Okno() {

    }

    public void createGUI() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        buttonExit = new JButton("Exit");
        buttonWyjscie = new JButton("Wyjscie");
        // Sluchacz sluchacz = new Sluchacz();

        // buttonExit.addActionListener(sluchacz);
        buttonExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(40, 120, 80), 4));

        ImagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        ImagePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 4));
        jp.add(buttonExit);
        add(jp);
        add(ImagePanel);

        setVisible(true);
        slajd();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void slajd() {
        try {
            File f = new File(".");
            File[] tablicaPlikow = f.listFiles();
            for (File el : tablicaPlikow) {

                String rozszerzenie = el.getName().substring(
                        el.getName().length() - 3);

                if (rozszerzenie.equals("jpg") || rozszerzenie.equals("peg")) {
                    System.out.println(rozszerzenie);
                    ImagePanel.setImage(el);
                }
                repaint();
            }
            setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Okno().createGUI();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
    }

    public ImagePanel(String sciezka) {
        setImage(new File(sciezka));
    }

    public void setImage(File plik) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(plik);
            System.out.println("tutaj");
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (image != null) {
            Image b = image.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    Image.SCALE_FAST);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What have been your attempts?  Why have not them worked?  In what way they didn't accomplish what you expected them to do?  Any error message, exception, or undesired behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleeping in the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) prevents swing from doing the painting, so you see only the last image. Instead of sleeping in the event dispatch thread, use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to do repeated tasks:

```
private final ActionListener timerTask = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        // Whatever you need to to that
        showNextImage();
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer(1000, timerTask);
timer.start();
```

If loading the images is taking long time, consider using a [background task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for preloading the next one in memory, without blocking the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer could be:  in method `slajd`, after call to `repaint();`, add

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

However, this is completely contrary to the event-based nature of Swing, and in this particular case doesn't even work because, for efficiency reasons, Swing does not execute `repaint()` calls immediately.  It "collects" and executes them only once after all event processing has concluded.  If you include an sleep period (or any other long-running operation) in an event handler (directly or indirectly), repainting will be delayed and the application be extremely unresponsive to the point, as in this case, of not really be working.

What you need to do is in `createGUI` instantiate a Swing Timer (`javax.swing.Timer`; do not confuse it with `java.util.Timer`, or `Timer` classes in a few other packages) that fires every 1 second instead of calling `slajd()`.  First firing should be immediate, or you could include code to display the first file.  The associated listener, which would replace `slajd()` should keep track of the next  file to display.  You will most probably want to make this listener a full-fledged class with fields to support this tracking, a pointer to the `ImagePanel` where to display files, etc.

For more information, read [Java's Tutorial on How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: 1)  Because it would work (and I would probably use it) if the question were all the problem.  2)  Because I have been having too many black-outs at home and wanted to save my response.  I did a few other partial saves after that too, and also 3)  Because my answers (please check them if you want) are usually long and (hopefully) complete, while some askers only want a quick response.

Comment: Not really.  To be consistent with my point 3) above, I will explain why Thread.sleep does not really work.  Thanks a lot for your help in making this a better answer.